# The right way to aggregate and combine RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a customer table that hosts information about several processes for each customer.

The goal is to extract features for each customer and each process. This means every feature is an mostly an aggregate or sort-compare computation on a `.groupby(customerID, processID)` object.

However, the goal is to be able to add more and more features over time. So basically the user should be able to define a new functions with some filters, metrics and aggregations, and add this new function to a pool of functions which operate on the table.

The output should be a customerID, processID table, with all features.

So I startet a little minimal working example:

```
l = [('CM1','aa1', 100,0.1),('CM1','aa1', 110,0.2),\
     ('CM1','aa1', 110,0.9),('CM1','aa1', 100,1.5),\
     ('CX2','bb9', 100,0.1),('CX2','bb9', 100,0.2),\
    ('CX2','bb9', 110,6.0),('CX2','bb9', 100,0.18)]

rdd = sc.parallelize(l)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,['customid','procid','speed','timestamp'])

+--------+------+-----+---------+
|customid|procid|speed|timestamp|
+--------+------+-----+---------+
|     CM1|   aa1|  100|      0.1|
|     CM1|   aa1|  110|      0.2|
|     CM1|   aa1|  110|      0.9|
|     CM1|   aa1|  100|      1.5|
|     CX2|   bb9|  100|      0.1|
|     CX2|   bb9|  100|      0.2|
|     CX2|   bb9|  110|      6.0|
|     CX2|   bb9|  100|     0.18|
+--------+------+-----+---------+
```

Then i define 2 arbitrary feature, which get extracted by these functions:

```
def extr_ft_1 (proc_data, limit=100):

    proc_data = proc_data.filter(proc_data.speed > limit).agg(count(proc_data.speed))

    proc_data = proc_data.select(col('count(speed)').alias('speed_feature'))

    proc_data.show()

    return proc_data


def extr_ft_0 (proc_data):

    max_t = proc_data.agg(spark_max(proc_data.timestamp))

    min_t = proc_data.agg(spark_min(proc_data.timestamp))

    max_t = max_t.select(col('max(timestamp)').alias('max'))

    min_t = min_t.select(col('min(timestamp)').alias('min'))

    X = max_t.crossJoin(min_t)

    X = X.withColumn('time_feature', X.max+X.min)

    X = X.drop(X.min).drop(X.max)

    X.show()

    return (X)
```

They return 1-element RRDs which just hold an aggregate value.
Next, all feature functions are applied for a given process and combined in a result RDD for each process:

```
def get_proc_features(proc, data, *features):

    proc_data = data.filter( data.customid == proc)

    features_for_proc = [feature_value(proc_data) for feature_value in features]



    for number, feature in enumerate(features_for_proc):

        if number == 0:

            l = [(proc,'dummy')]

            rdd = sc.parallelize(l)

            df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,['customid','dummy']) 

            df = df.drop(df.dummy)

            df.show()

            features_for_proc_rdd = feature

            features_for_proc_rdd = features_for_proc_rdd.crossJoin(df)

            continue

        features_for_proc_rdd = features_for_proc_rdd.crossJoin(feature)

        features_for_proc_rdd.show()

    return features_for_proc_rdd
```

They last step is to append all rows which contain the features for each process to one dataframe:

```
for number, proc in  enumerate(customer_list_1):

    if number == 0:

        #results = get_trip_features(trip, df, extr_ft_0, extr_ft_1)
        results = get_proc_features(proc, df, *extr_feature_funcs)

        continue

    results = results.unionAll(get_proc_features(proc, df, *extr_feature_funcs))

results.show()
```

The chain of transformations goes like this:

get features 1 and 2 for customer 1:

```
+------------+
|time_feature|
+------------+
|         1.6|
+------------+

+-------------+
|speed_feature|
+-------------+
|            2|
+-------------+
```

Combine them to:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+
|time_feature|customid|speed_feature|
+------------+--------+-------------+
|         1.6|     CM1|            2|
+------------+--------+-------------+
```

Do the same for customer 2 and append all RDDs to the final result RDD:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+
|time_feature|customid|speed_feature|
+------------+--------+-------------+
|         1.6|     CM1|            2|
|         6.1|     CX2|            1|
+------------+--------+-------------+
```

If I run the code on the cluster, it works for 2 customers.
But when I tested it on a reasonable amount of customers, i get mostly GC and heap memory errors.

Do I work with to many RDDs here? I am afraid my code is very inefficient but I don't know where to start to optimize it. I think I just call one action at the end (I drop all shows() in live mode and just collect() the very last RDD).
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What configurations did you use for your cluster (number of executors, memory,...) what is the size of your data. Note that if you've increased memory without increasing the memory Overhead it won't be effective

Comment: The Data is around 160 TB and I think it is 200 executors. About the memory I don't now.

Comment: Your code needs refactoring, the problem is not the RDD but the fact that you filter it to work on unitary keys and then cross join. Iterating through values makes you lose the distributed aspect of pyspark. The best way to do it is using dataframes and window functions. Keep in mind that you should always keep your one work table if you don't need features from another one. I'll help you out, but first what's `customer_list_1`  and `extr_feature_funcs`?

Comment: customer_list_1 = ['CM1', 'CX2'], and extr_feature_funcs = (extr_ft_0, extr_ft_1). It was meant to be a parameter touple, where one could add any feature extracting function witch is desired  to be applied on the data. I saw your proper answer Marie, im on moba right now and try it out at home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs refactoring, the problem is not the RDD but the fact that you filter it to work on unitary keys and then cross join. Iterating through values makes you lose the distributed aspect of pyspark. Keep in mind that you should always keep your one work table if you don't need features from another one.

The best way to do it is using dataframes and window functions.

First let's rewrite your functions:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
def extr_ft_1 (proc_data, w, limit=100):
    return proc_data.withColumn(
        "speed_feature", 
        psf.sum((proc_data.speed > limit).cast("int")).over(w)
    )

def extr_ft_0(proc_data, w):
    return proc_data.withColumn(
        "time_feature", 
        psf.min(proc_data.timestamp).over(w) + psf.max(proc_data.timestamp).over(w)
    )
```

Where `w` is a window spec:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("customid")
df1 = extr_ft_1(df, w)
df0 = extr_ft_0(df1, w)
df0.show()

    +--------+------+-----+---------+-------------+------------+
    |customid|procid|speed|timestamp|speed_feature|time_feature|
    +--------+------+-----+---------+-------------+------------+
    |     CM1|   aa1|  100|      0.1|            2|         1.6|
    |     CM1|   aa1|  110|      0.2|            2|         1.6|
    |     CM1|   aa1|  110|      0.9|            2|         1.6|
    |     CM1|   aa1|  100|      1.5|            2|         1.6|
    |     CX2|   bb9|  100|      0.1|            1|         6.1|
    |     CX2|   bb9|  100|      0.2|            1|         6.1|
    |     CX2|   bb9|  110|      6.0|            1|         6.1|
    |     CX2|   bb9|  100|     0.18|            1|         6.1|
    +--------+------+-----+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Here we never lose information (we keep all the lines) so if you want to add extra features you can. If you want a final aggregated results just run it through a `groupBy("customid")`.

Note that you can also modify the aggregation key in the window spec to include `procid` for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much Marie! I tested it today and it works like a charm :) No memory errors and the scrip run faster than expected.

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad I could help :)